# How to get the first sentence before a defined string with Regex

Tags: python, regex, screen-scraping

I am doing some scraping and I want to scrape a certain part of a src element but not sure how to do this with regex. Are there any regex ninja's here who can help me?

```
srcset="https://cimg.co/w/articles/1/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 150w, https://cimg.co/w/articles/2/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 300w, https://cimg.co/w/articles/3/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 600w, https://cimg.co/w/articles/4/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 1200w"
```

I want the first url before 1200w. So the outcome should be:

```
https://cimg.co/w/articles/4/5ca/f022bb06dc.png
```

Why I need regex for this, the last element:

[image]

Thanks in advance and have a great weekend :)

Comment: You need to show an attempt at completing it yourself. Use https://regex101.com/ lovely tool for regex

Comment: I came until this: `.+?(?=1200w)` then got stuck. Also used regex101.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for Regex. You can do this with string methods `split` and `partition`:

```
In [181]: srcset = "https://cimg.co/w/articles/1/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 150w, https://cimg.co/w/articles/2/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 300w, https://cimg.co/w/articles/3/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 600w, https://cimg.co/w/arti
     ...: cles/4/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 1200w"                                                                                                                                                                  

In [182]: def get_url(srcset): 
     ...:     for str_ in srcset.split(','): 
     ...:         url, _, ext = str_.strip().partition(' ') 
     ...:         if ext == '1200w': 
     ...:             return url 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [183]: get_url(srcset)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[183]: 'https://cimg.co/w/articles/4/5ca/f022bb06dc.png'
```

Assuming `,` does not come in URLs.

---

If you must use Regex, you can do:

```
https?://\S+(?=\s+1200w\b)
```

So:

```
In [184]: re.search(r'https?://\S+(?=\s+1200w\b)', srcset).group()                                                                                                                                          
Out[184]: 'https://cimg.co/w/articles/4/5ca/f022bb06dc.png'
```

- `https?://\S+` matches the URL
- The zero-width postive lookahead, `(?=\s+1200w\b)`, ensures that the URL is followed by one or more spaces(`\s+`), then `1200w`

OTOH, if you don't feel comfortable with the HTTP scheme based matching, you can match the start or `,`, and grab the first captured group:

```
In [185]: re.search(r'(?:^|,\s+)(\S+)\s+1200w\b', srcset).group(1)                                                                                                                                          
Out[185]: 'https://cimg.co/w/articles/4/5ca/f022bb06dc.png'
```

Comment: I am using Django Dynamic Scraper, therefore I need regex to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
a = 'srcset="https://cimg.co/w/articles/1/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 150w, https://cimg.co/w/articles/2/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 300w, https://cimg.co/w/articles/3/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 600w, https://cimg.co/w/articles/4/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 1200w"'

a = a.replace('srcset=', '').replace('"', '').split(',')
done = a[len(a)-1].strip().split(' ')[0]
print(done)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

[`[^\s,"]+(?=\s+1200w\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/LFEdHG/1)

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `r"600w, (.*) 1200w"` , you Group 1 should return the url you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `.+?(?=1200w)` will match any character except a newline 1+ times until what is on the right is `1200`.

To get a more specific match using a regex, you could use a capturing group:

```
\bsrcset="[^"]* (https?://\S+)\s+1200w"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xfaOS1/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Yq9wD7)

For example:

```
import re
regex = r'\bsrcset="[^"]* (https?://\S+)\s+1200w"'
test_str = """srcset=\"https://cimg.co/w/articles/1/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 150w, https://cimg.co/w/articles/2/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 300w, https://cimg.co/w/articles/3/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 600w, https://cimg.co/w/articles/4/5ca/f022bb06dc.png 1200w\""""

matches = re.search(regex, test_str)
if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
```

Result

```
https://cimg.co/w/articles/4/5ca/f022bb06dc.png
```